# Jest reuse mock next/route object

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js

I have mock like:

```
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  push: jest.fn(),
  events: {
    on: jest.fn(),
    off: jest.fn()
  },
  beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null)
}));
```

I need use it in planty of places that why i want reuse it. What I try,
I created folder `__mocks__` and file mock.js.

mock.js :

```
export default () => jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  push: jest.fn(),
  events: {
    on: jest.fn(),
    off: jest.fn()
  },
  beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null)
}));
```

And in my component.test.js import mock.
component.test.js :

```
import '../__mocks__/mocks';
```

But in it when I render component I have error:

```
  it('should mount and sub to "routerChangeStart"', async () => {
    render(<LoseChangesWarning dirty isSubmitting={false} />);
    await wait(() => {
      expect(Router.events.on).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      expect(Router.beforePopState).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Error message: 
*No router instance found.
    You should only use "next/router" inside the client side of your app.*

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64932507/861993

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Create a file mock in the folder: `<rootDir>/jest/__mocks__/routerMock.js` and add mock

```js
jest.mock('next/router', () => ({
  push: jest.fn(),
  back: jest.fn(),
  events: {
    on: jest.fn(),
    off: jest.fn(),
  },
  beforePopState: jest.fn(() => null),
  useRouter: () => ({
    push: jest.fn(),
  }),
}));
```

2 - In the `jest.config.js` file, adds this:

```js
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
```

3 - In `jest.setup.js` file, import `routerMock.js`:

```js
import './jest/__mocks__/routerMock';
```

4 - Test on your component

```js
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
import Router from 'next/router'

 it('when the "next page" button is clicked', () => {
    render(<StuffComponent />);
    const button = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Next page' })

    userEvent.click(button)

    expect(Router.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/next-page');

 });
```