# Jest - one function mocks file for multiple test files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to have something like this:

`mockFunctions.ts`

```
jest.mock('../utils', () => {
  return {
     getNumbers: () => [1,2,3]
  }
})
```

`__tests__/test1.ts`

```
---import from mockFunctions---
...
it('After adding another number array has more elements', () => {
   const numbers = <get these numbers using mock function>
   expect([...numbers, 11]).toHaveLength(4);
})
```

`__tests__/test2.ts`

```
---import from mockFunctions---
...
it('After removing a number, array has less elements', () => {
   const numbers = <get these numbers using mock function>
   expect(numbers.filter(x => x>1)).toHaveLength(2);
})
```

Is it possible to have one file where mocked functions are implemented, and then import them in multiple tests files?

Comment: Hi, you can define the mocks inside function and then call that function where you need it.

Comment: @lissettdm Could you give me an example how to do it?

Comment: Reusable mocks is what `__mocks__` are for. Did you try it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some alternative to accomplish this:

1. Add `__mocks__` directory inside utils folder. See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks

utils/index.js

```
export const  getNumbers= () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

->utils/`__mocks__`/index.js

```
export const  getNumbers= () => [3, 4];
```

jest.config.js

```
{ 
   "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"
    ]
}
```

jestSetup.js

```
jest.mock("../utils"); // will apply to all tests
```

2. Add mock definition directly in jestSetup.js

jest.config.js

```
{ 
   "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"
    ]
}
```

jestSetup.js

```
  jest.mock("../utils", () => ({
     getNumbers: () => [3, 4]
  }));
```

or create a file with mocks

mocks.js

```
  jest.mock("../utils", () => ({
     getNumbers: () => [3, 4]
  }));
```

jestSetup.js

```
  import './mocks.js'
```

If you don't want to use mocks on specific test, you can call:

```
jest.unmock('../utils')
```

See: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestunmockmodulename

Comment: I think one step further now, can I use two other mocks in the same tests directory? For example two files using mocks from one file, and another two files using mocks from second file. I haven't found it on the webpages you attached to this answer, and this answer can provide only one endpoint implementation for all the tests

Comment: Could you attach a link where you have this scenario, so that I can understand it more clearly?