# Can I have Jest Mocks in a different file and import it into my test file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing

I have a custom Hook in a file and I have to mock it quite often for multiple tests.
Can I have the mock in a separate file and then just import it into the test?

Hook file

```
export default function myHook(key) {
    const { state, app } = StateFromSomePlace();

    const setParameter = useCallback(
        newValue => {
            // do something
        },
        [app, key, state.something]
    );

    if (key) {
       // do something
        const parameter = // something;
        return [parameter, setParameter];
    }
}
```

i want to mock the above using jest to return something (which i can), but i want to do so in an helper/setup file so i can use it in multiple test by just importing the mock.

Thanks for the help in advance. :)

Comment: Kush, did you find a solution?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64932507/861993