# I have a jest mock how can i import to multiple test files

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, next.js

I am writing some tests for some components that use Next/Image. As i keep getting errors i decided to mock the module like this:

```
jest.mock(
    `next/image`,
    () =>
        function Image({ src, alt }) {
            // eslint-disable-next-line @next/next/no-img-element
            return <img src={src} alt={alt} />;
        },
);
```

So far so good, this works great. BUT i have multiple components that use next/image and i need to use this mock in those test files. My current solution is to copy pasta, but that's stupid. I've tried to create a module of sorts that i can just include in config/setup.js or just import it. but i cant seem to figure out how to do it.

Help would be much appreciated, i'm fairly certain this is a simple thing and im likely having a Friday post lunch brain fart.

Comment: What did you try?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest - one function mocks file for multiple test files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64930354/jest-one-function-mocks-file-for-multiple-test-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [putting a mock](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules) into `__mocks__` folder.

As mentioned in documentation:

> Manual mocks are defined by writing a module in a `__mocks__/` subdirectory immediately adjacent to the module. For example, to mock a module called user in the models directory, create a file called user.js and put it in the `models/__mocks__` directory.

Comment: Is it possible to define multiple mocks at `folder/__mocks__` and select - somehow - which one to use ?